# N+1 HTTP calls batching with simultaneous queue

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, concurrency, reactive

Suppose,I have a method which fetches data from an HTTP API

```
public R getResource(String id){
      //HTTP call to 
      return fetch("http://example.com/api/id")
}
```

But
http://example.org/api/ supports multiple Ids at a time say
http://example.org/api/id1,id2,id3

In a multi-threaded environment, i want to block, until i have collected 'm' ids and then in one shot, get data from the API.

Also, to avoid infinite/long blocks, there should be a wait timeout.

for m=5
Lets say 20 threads arrive concurrently to call this method, then 4 batches of requests should be sent to the HTTP api.

Any implementation suggestion or existing frameworks to support this batching.

Edit suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BlockingQueue` with a thread doing `BlockingQueue::poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` with the timeout computed e.g., so that the first request waits no longer than some fixed duration.

The polling thread will gather the IDs from the queue in its own list until it either has `m` IDs or the maximum waiting duration gets reached. There should be only one such thread.

In the above list, there should be entries containing both the ID and a `CompletableFuture<R>`, which gets completed using the result of the call. The future is what you give to the caller. Instead of a list, you may want to use a `Map<String, CompletableFuture<R>>` so than on request completion, you can complete the futures easily. Actually, the queue should contain the future, too, so you can give it back to the caller.

A rough sketch:

```
class ResourceMultigetter<R> {
    private final BlockingQueue<Map.Entry<String, CompletableFuture<R>>> newEntries = ...;

    private final Map<String, CompletableFuture<R>> collected = ...;

    private long millisOfFirstWaitingRequest;

    private volatile boolean stopped;

    class Processor implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() { // run by the polling thread
            while (!stopped) {
                final Map.Entry<String, CompletableFuture<R>> e = newEntries.poll(....);
                if (e == null) {
                    if (!timeHasElapsed()) continue;
                } else {
                    if (collected.isEmpty()) {
                        millisOfFirstWaitingRequest = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    collected.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                    if (collected.size() < m && !timeHasElapsed()) continue;

                }
                final List<String> processedIds = callTheServer();
                processedIds.forEach(id -> collected.remove(id));
            }
        }
    }

    public CompletableFuture<R> enqueue(String id) {
        final CompletableFuture<R> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
        newEntries.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(id, result));
        return result;
    }
}
```

You'd initialize it like

```
ResourceMultigetter resourceMultigetter = new ResourceMultigetter();
new Thread(resourceMultigetter.new Processor()).start();
```

The client code would do something like

```
R r = resourceMultigetter.enqueue(id); // this blocks
```